# Setting up asp.net test server

Tags: asp.net, vmware

I am creating a website in asp.net MVC 4 and am wondering the best way to set up a test server?

I am doing this from home and would like a way for my friend to test my code from a different location (his home).  What would the best way to go about this? Build a local server that he only has access to?  VMWare?  Online web hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use a VM and set up a server.
NOTE! that this would require your friend to redirect your IP Adress to the host name you will set for your website on the IIS of your VM.
He can easily do that by changing his Hosts at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Another option would be actually to purchase a domain (that you will need anyway eventually)
The purchase a hosting package (that you will also need anyway eventually).
Then setup your website on a sub domain in that hosting server e.g. dev.myDomain.com